# uWSGI resets PythonHome

Tags: python, django, uwsgi

I am using nginx+django+uwsgi to deploy my application, but I found that it doesn't work on my host. The error is like this:

```
[uWSGI] parsing config file forum/uwsgi.xml
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.1 (64bit) on [Tue Feb 11 10:42:47 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.7.3 on 11 February 2014 09:35:41
os: Linux-2.6.35-32-server #64 SMP Fri Jan 13 06:36:08 CST 2012
nodename: AY120826095xxxx
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 1
current working directory: /home/foo/git/project
detected binary path: /home/foo/git/software/uwsgi-2.0.1/uwsgi
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:8630 fd 3
Python version: 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:23:21)  [GCC 4.7.3]
Set PythonHome to /home/foo/software/uwsgi-2.0.1
ImportError: No module named site
```

I deploy it in my local computer, and it works. How do I solve this problem?

The config file is as follows:

```
<uwsgi>
  <socket>127.0.0.1:8630</socket>
  <chdir>/home/foo/git/project/forum</chdir>
  <module>wsgi</module>
</uwsgi>
```

and the the console output on my local computer is :

```
[uWSGI] parsing config file forum/uwsgi.xml
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.1 (64bit) on [Tue Feb 11 14:24:59 2014] ***
compiled with version: 4.7.3 on 11 February 2014 07:24:13
os: Linux-3.8.0-19-generic #29-Ubuntu SMP Wed Apr 17 18:16:28 UTC 2013
nodename: alienware
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 8
current working directory: /home/foo/project/osqa
detected binary path: /home/foo/uwsgi-2.0.1/uwsgi
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your processes number limit is 62679
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1024
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:8630 fd 6
Python version: 2.7.4 (default, Sep 26 2013, 03:23:21)  [GCC 4.7.3]
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x23a6100
python threads support enabled
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72760 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 0 seconds on interpreter 0x23a6100 pid: 21702 (default app)
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 21702, cores: 1)
```

Comment: What does `forum/uwsgi.xml` look like?

Comment: yeah, what does your config file look like, or how are you calling uwsgi from the command line?

Comment: What is the output on your local computer using the same config?

Comment: the config of uwsgi is :      <uwsgi>
  <socket>127.0.0.1:8630</socket>
  <chdir>/home/foo/git/project/forum</chdir>
  <module>wsgi</module>
</uwsgi> and I start it using uwsgi -x forum/uwsgi.xml

Comment: @uuball It would be better if edited your question to put config and local output there. Especially the output because it will be a lot easier to read.

Comment: i edit this question, and put some details about the config file

Comment: @uuball Are you using virtualenv? If so, are you using virtualenv for python 2.7 and not some other version on the host machine?

Answer (score 3):

If you're **not** using Virtualenv, you must add the `pythonpath` directive to your config file:

```
pythonpath = /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
pythonpath = /usr/lib/python2.7
```

This is in the .ini syntax, please adapt it to your XML configuration.

Comment: I had modified the config file as follows:                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
<uwsgi>
  <socket>127.0.0.1:8630</socket>
  <chdir>/home/foo/git/project/forum</chdir>
  <pythonpath>/usr/lib/python2.7</pythonpath>
  <module>wsgi</module>
</uwsgi>
but it still doesn't work

Comment: @uuball does it give the same error? Why only one path? i use the both i posted on Ubuntu to include all the packages installed in python.

Answer (score 0):

Add to ini file this:
`plugins = python`